# Or conditions on multiple fields in parse javascript query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, conditional-statements, parse-cloud-code

While I build the query in cloud code, I have or conditions on fields as well as other conditions on other fields.
For an instance, I'd like to get the records which has specified zip code or empty value.
Query would be as following if I use Parse.Query.or();

```
    var Offer = Parse.Object.extend("Offer");
    var query1 = new Parse.Query(Offer);
    query1.doesNotExist("zipCode");

    var query2 = new Parse.Query(Offer);
    query2.exists("zipCode");
    query2.equalTo("zipCode", zipCode);

    query = Parse.Query.or(query1, query2);
```

I have no problem if I have a such condition but it's tough to have similar conditions on multiple fields.

Comment: How is it tough to add another query to `or` query? `query3.equalTo("name", name)`

Comment: I have another or condition on another field just like above.